# ActionScript 3 & Runtime Resources

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cookies

So, I've been working on a project in AS3 and I've come across yet another peculiar bit of behavior.

**Background:** It's a turned based game. I've been optimizing it for the past week and now it runs like butter (consistently!);

**Issue:** However, when I try to continue playing from a saved game, it runs less consistently. Specifically, it will run the first few turns normally, then it will begin to degrade in performance dramatically until it freezes my computer. Please note, this only happens during battle, not during the menus or during any other time.

Is there something regarding Actionscript that I'm missing? I'm saving the game with cookies using the built in SharedObject class. The code I'm using to save and load the data is below (I also use the byte array class).

```
public static function saveGame():void
{
    /// save the game using byte array
    registerClassAlias("Mob", Mob);
    registerClassAlias("Skill", Skill);
    var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var savedData:* = Main.glblPlayer.setSaveObject(); 
    ba.writeObject(savedData);
    ba.position = 0; 
    so.data.game5 = ba; 
    so.flush();
}

public static function loadGame():Boolean
{
    if (so.data.hasOwnProperty("game5"))
    {
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba = so.data.game5;
        ba.position = 0;
        var loadedData:Object = ba.readObject();
        glblPlayer.loadSaveObject( loadedData ); 

        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        so.data.game = new Object();
        return false; 
    }
}
```

I just double checked the above code and tested it a bit more with some variation. If it's loaded 1-3 times, it's fine, but after that the performance degrades during battle with each turn.  I have no idea how the technical stuff of ActionScript works or how it saves resources aside from that it's cookies and it's in the cache.

Can anyone shed some light on this by maybe going a bit more into how saving/loading with flash games are done in AS3? Or is "use sharedObject" all there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a profiler (like Adobe scout) to see what causes the problem.

If I had to guess, it's because your (de-)serialisation routines do not work properly and have a memory leak. But again arguing about this or looking at the code wondering what might be the problem is a pointless endeavour. Use a profiler to see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: So, I ran it and it said "other overhead" takes up a massive amount of the processing power, dramatically lowering the frame rate. Have you ever heard of such a thing? Or what overhead is supposed to be?

Comment: @Naomi Dennis No, sorry. This might be a good follow up question. Or maybe you find something helpful in the Adobe forums, like here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1114767